# Display Issues with SVG Text in Jupyter Notebook on GitHub

Tags: python, html, github, svg, jupyter-notebook

Consider creating a SVG to be displayed in a Jupyter Notebook:

```py
from IPython.display import display, SVG

svg_str = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Add text -->
  <text x="10" y="30" font-family="Verdana" font-size="24">HYPHEN: -</text>
  <text x="10" y="60" font-family="Verdana" font-size="24">FIGURE DASH: ‒</text>
  <text x="10" y="90" font-family="Verdana" font-size="24">EN DASH: –</text>
  <text x="10" y="120" font-family="Verdana" font-size="24">EM DASH: —</text>
  <text x="10" y="150" font-family="Verdana" font-size="24">HORIZONTAL BAR: ―</text>
</svg>
'''

display(SVG(svg_str))
```

It displays correctly on my local Jupyter Notebook (VS Code):

[image]

However, when uploaded to GitHub, the text doesn't display correctly (Chrome or Firefox):

[image]

I encountered this issue because the negative sign used in Plotly SVGs doesn't render correctly.